# Changing an image using swift for iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

So I am trying to load a picture programmatically using Swift and I am having some trouble. I can change the UIImage of a view using the Attributes Inspector, so I know the picture I am using is added properly and I am using the right name.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myPicture: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        myPicture.image = UIImage(named:"myNewPic")
    }  
}
```

I think there might be some setting I am missing in Attributes inspector or something since the code is pretty simple and I know the image is added properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you positive your IBOutlet is connected properly?

Comment: You assign a value to the UIImageView's "image" property. For example if you have "foo.png" in your bundle

    imageView.image = UIImage(named:"myNewPic")

Comment: where u store the image in assets or bundle resource

Comment: What problem do you have exactly ? Image is not displayed ? or displayed but not correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your image name is correct. You have image properly in xcode and your outlet is properly connected

add image with extension if you are not using assets for images. like `myNewPic.png` or `myNewPic.jpg` whatever extension it is.
So, your code should be like,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myPicture: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()    
       myPicture.image = UIImage(named:"myNewPic.png") //or .jpg or else
    }  
}
```

**another choice**

if you load image from assets use`myNewPic` if you load from bundle use `myNewPic.png` (with extensions).

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "myNewPic") {

     myPicture.image = img

} else {

   myPicture.image = UIImage(named:"myNewPic.Imageextensions")
}
```

Comment: It was issue with file extensions.

Comment: @Lion - I am not assign the negative Vote

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : I have comment for those who down voted without reading or seeing answer at least once

Comment: ya your answer is fine ,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : thanks for improving answer. It makes better solution. :)